# my input array keeps over writing itself

Tags: java, arrays

Every time i pass an object to my array, it overwrites the previous entry. Can anybody spot why this is happening?

addbook() - when i put in name, and author it assigns a value , but when enter another title and author, it overwrites the previous entry.

```
public class library {
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int count = 0;
    public static void main(String [] args){
         addBook();
    }   // Main end
    static void addBook(){
        loanbook [] loanArray = new loanbook[5];

        String title,author;
        int choice;
        boolean onLoan;
        loanbook book1; // TESTING ONLY
        for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
            System.out.print("Press 1 for Fiction or 2 for Non Fiction: ");  // sub menu for fiction and non fiction
            choice = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (choice == 1){

                System.out.println("Please enter book title: ");
                title = keyboard.nextLine();
                title = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter book author: ");
                author = keyboard.nextLine();
                onLoan = false; // not used yet
                book1 = new fiction(title,author);
                System.out.println(book1.toString());
                loanArray[x] = new loanbook(title,author);

            }
            else if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.println("Please enter book title: ");
                title = keyboard.nextLine();
                title = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter book author: ");
                author = keyboard.nextLine();
                onLoan = false; // not used yet
                book1 = new nonfiction(title,author);
                System.out.println(book1.toString());
                loanArray[x] = new loanbook(title,author);
            }
        }
    }
} // Library end
```

My Loanbook class

```
public class loanbook {
    private String title,author;
    private int bookID, count = 0;

    public loanbook(String pTitle,String pAuthor){
        bookID = count;
        title = pTitle;
        author = pAuthor;
        count++;
    }  // Constructor
    public void setTitle(String pTitle){
        title = pTitle;
    } // setTitle
    protected String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }   // getTitle
    protected String getAuthor(){
        return author;
    }   // getAuthor
    public String toString(){
        return " BookID: "+ bookID+"\n" + " Title: "+ getTitle()+"\n" +" Author : "+ getAuthor()+ "\n";
    }
}  // loanbook
```

Comment: Are the variables in your `loanbook` class `static`?  Please show that class.  Also, by convention, Java class names are usually capitalized and camel case, e.g. `LoanBook` and `Library`.

Comment: This code looks OK.  How do you know that your are over-writing the array value?

Comment: What makes you say _"it gets over written"_?

Comment: Define "pass an object to my array" and "overwrites previous entry", especially what is "previous". At the end of execution `addBook` local variable `loanArray` should have five elements. These are discarded so they won't be available after the method completes.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to make `count` `static`. I'm assuming you want the count to go up every time a new book is created. Without the static, the count value will not persist ever time a book is created, so your `bookID` will always be 0 for every book. That *may* be why you think *"it's getting overwriten"*. I'm not totally sure because you haven't really explained what that means.

```
private int bookID; 
public static int count = 0;           <-- static 

public loanbook(String pTitle,String pAuthor){
    bookID = count;
    title = pTitle;
    author = pAuthor;
    count++;
}
```

Or better yet, just avoid the `count` variable. You do the same as you would with the `count`. So `count` is unnecessary.

```
public static int bookID 0;

public loanbook(String pTitle,String pAuthor){
    title = pTitle;
    author = pAuthor;
    bookId++;
}
```

Also, I don't know what you're planning to with `loanbook book1;`, but it is used every time in the loop, so I could see this being the possible *"it is getting overwritten"* problem. Assuming `fiction` and `nonfiction` extend `loanbook`

Also I don't see a need for the `count` in the library class. You can get rid of that.

**Update:**

Assuming you want the `fiction` or `nonfiction` book (and they both extend `loanbook) in your`loanArray` may you want something like this

```
loanbook book = new fiction(title,author);
System.out.println(book1.toString());
loanArray[x] = book;
```

Comment: He is not even using the `count` variable in his code, so making it static will not help.

Comment: count variable is linked to bookId. `bookId` is printed is in the `toString`. When it is printed it will show the same

Comment: I am not disagreeing with your code, but the OP's code fails to show how "it gets over written"?

Comment: Look before down voting

Comment: Obviously you are disagreeing

Comment: You may be looking at the wrong `count`. There's one in both class. The one I am referring to is the one in the `loanbook` class. That's the one that needs to get persisted as it makes reference to the `bookId`